# How to underline text as part of a label?

Tags: graphviz

Following is code using dot language.

```
subgraph cluster1
            {
            node[style=filled];
            color=blue;
            b0->b1;

            label ="Tada"; // I want this to show as underlined.
            }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [HTML-like labels](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#html) and the `<u>` tag:

```
digraph cluster1
{
    node[style=filled, color=blue];
    b0->b1;

    label = <<u>Tada</u>>; // I want this to show as underlined.
}
```

This is the result:

[image: Tada!]

Note that your `color=blue` statement wasn't applied to any element. I moved it into `node`.

As pointed out in the comments, this currently only works for svg output. I tried with png and pdf on my Mac running 10.14.6 and they weren't underlined.

Comment: Attention: "these markups are currently only available via the cairo and svg renderers" - http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#html

Comment: ^ this means that using `-Tpng` with a Homebrew-installed graphviz won't render underlines (or bold, or italics), because the cairo renderer apparently isn't available; you have to use `-Tsvg` instead.