# How can i underline as apecific field in a graphviz record

Tags: markdown, graphviz, plantuml, mermaid, relational-model

Referring to [How to underline text as part of a label?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22456268/how-to-underline-text-as-part-of-a-label/22458509#22458509) where underlining is explained.

Is ist possible to combine underlining with column-layout?

[image]

```
digraph g {
graph [ rankdir = "LR"];
node [
shape = "record"
];
"other" [
label = <<u>Tada</u>>;
];
"something" [
label = " name | property"
];
}
```

I am open for suggestions with other frameworks like mermaid (preferably supported by hackmd)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [HTML-like label (table)](https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#html) (using `<u>` tags inside a table cell), although it's pretty heavy:

```
digraph g {
graph [ rankdir = "LR"];
node [
shape = "plaintext"
];
"something" [
    label=<
        <TABLE ALIGN="LEFT" border="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="4">
            <TR>
                <TD>name</TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
                <TD><u>property</u></TD>
            </TR>
        </TABLE>
    >
];
}
```

[image]